# Finding a basis for $V$ such that the matrix of $T:V\to V$ is strictly upper triangular

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $T:V\to V$ be a linear map on a vector space $V$ of dimension $n$. Assume that there exists $k\in \mathbb{N}$, such that for each $i$, $0\leq i\leq k$, there exists a subspace $V_i$ of $V$ (denoted $V_i \leq V$) with the following properties:
>
> 1. $V_i \subset V_{i+1}$ for $0\leq i\leq k-1$
> 2. $V_i \neq V_{i+1}$ for $0\leq i\leq k-1$
> 3. $V_0 = \{0\}$ and $V_k = V$
> 4. $TV_i \subseteq V_{i-1}$ for $1\leq i\leq k$
>
> Then there exists a basis for $V$ such that the matrix of $T$ with respect to this basis is *strictly upper triangular* (i.e. all non-zero entries lie above the diagonal only)

So, I'm in the search of a basis $\mathcal{B} = \{v_1,...,v_n\}$ which makes $[T]_{\mathcal{B}}$ strictly upper triangular. This would mean that $Tv_j = \text{span}(v_1,v_2,...,v_{j-1})$. Intuitively, it makes sense to think about considering the basis of $V_i$ and extending it to a basis for $V_{i+1}$ (until we reach $V_n$), but I'm not sure how to put this down formally. Moreover, it's a little bothering that we don't know what $k$ is. Is that a typographical error in the question? Possibly not.

Please help me with hints so that I can work further in the right direction!

Comment: For 4. It is probably $TV_i \subseteq V_i$ for $1 \le i \le k$.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net: It rather should be $TV_i\subseteq V_{i-1}$.

Comment: @Berci You're right. We're willing to get a **strictly** upper diagonal matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

Take $\{e_1, e_2, \dots , e_{i_1}\}$ as a basis of $V_1$.

And by induction if $\{e_1, e_2, \dots, e_{i_1}, e_{i_1+1}, e_{i_1+2}, \dots, e_{i_{l-1}}\}$ is a basis of $V_{l-1}$, complete it into a basis $\{e_1, e_2, \dots, e_{i_1}, e_{i_1+1}, e_{i_1+2}, \dots, e_{i_{l-1}}, e_{i_{l-1}+1},e_{i_{l-1}+2},\dots, e_{i_l}\}$ of $V_l$.

At the last step and as $V_k = V$, you'll ensure that you get a basis of $V$.

Then look at $T(e_i)$ for $1 \le i \le n$ to prove that the matrix of $T$ in the built basis is strictly upper diagonal.

Comment: Do you mean $V_{k-1}$ instead of $V_{l-1}$?

Comment: Indeed a typo in indices. I updated the answer.

Comment: I understand the idea about extending bases and finally obtaining a basis for $V$, but how do I ensure $TV_i \subseteq V_{i-1}$ at every step?

Comment: This is due to your point 4. $TV_i \subseteq V_{i-1}$ for $1 \le i \le k$.

Comment: Perfect! This argument seems to work like magic - we never really used the fact that $TV_i \subseteq V_{i-1}$ while extending the basis!

Comment: You're right. We don't need it to build the basis, but just to verify that the built basis satisfies the requirements.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Your attempt will work: just fix any basis $v_1,\dots,v_{d_1}$ of $V_1$, then extend it to a basis of $V_2$ by $v_{d_1+1},\dots,v_{d_2}$, and so on.. Here $d_i=\dim V_i$.